Unfollow doesn't work anymore
If I try to unfollow a post, this message appears:

and the "Following" remains:

I tried on both https://tex.stackexchange.com/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Confirmed. Duplicate or not... I cannot unfollow this question.
